# Allocate two-dimensional array

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, malloc

How can I allocate a bi-dimensional array using `malloc`? 
This is my current code:

```
typedef struct object product, *pprod;
struct object{
    int type;
    int quantity;
    pprod next;
};

pprod t[4][3];
```

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: What is the aim? To `malloc` some memory to use it as a `pprod[n][3]`?

Comment: Actually I need it to be pprod[n][m]

Comment: You can create a vector (singlePinter) with the size of n*m and access with [index/rowSize][index%rowSize] so you don`t have to create and array of pointers.

Comment: @demonofnight: C supports variable-length arrays, since 1999, so you do not need to do manual address arithmetic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To allocate memory in such a way that the layout is compatible with a normal two-dimensional array - or array of arrays - you need a pointer to an array of appropriate size,

```
pprod (*t)[m] = malloc(n * sizeof *t);
```

Thus `t` is a pointer to arrays of `m` elements of type `pprod`, and you can simply use it

```
t[i][j]
```

as if it were declared

```
pprod t[n][m];
```

(if `malloc` doesn't return `NULL`).

This allocation allocates a contiguous block of memory, unlike allocating a `pprod **` would.

(Note: If `m` is not a compile-time constant, that requires that the compiler supports variable length arrays, it would not work with MSVC.)

Comment: That's the message i'm getting in Xcode
"Initializer element is not a compile-time constant"

Comment: That variable length arrays are not supported? Hmm, I thought Xcode used llvm-gcc, and that should support VLAs. What's the compiler version you are using? Or are you perhaps compiling as C++? C++ doesn't have VLAs.

Comment: @CarlaPateiro "Initializer element is not a compile-time constant" looks like you try to initialise an array (or a `struct`) of static storage duration with something that is not a constant expression. Can you post the exact error message with the corresponding line of the source code?

Comment: The compiler version is: Apple LLVM compiler 4.2

This is what im trying to do:
pprod (*t)[3] = malloc(4 * sizeof *t);

Comment: @CarlaPateiro At file scope? You can't call `malloc` at file scope, you must do that in a function.

Answer (score 1):

For 2D array you should define a pointer like:

```
typedef struct obj OBJECT;
OBJECT **2Dptr = malloc (sizeof(OBJECT*)*rows)
for(i=0;i<rows;i++)
  2Dptr[i]=malloc(sizeof(OBJECT)*total_objects) //columns
```

There are other ways too, you can define array of pointers to your struct object.

```
if you want object[5][10]
you can create 5 pointers to array of 10 objects;
```

if you want the memory to be contiguous then you could do

```
*2Dptr=malloc(sizeof(OBJECT) * rows * cols);  //allocate contiguosly
**access_ptr = malloc(sizeof(OBJECT*) * rows);
for(i=0;i<row;i++)
   access_ptr[i]= 2Dptr+(i*cols);
```

Comment: downvote is great if downvoter lets me know what am i missing or wrong! so that everyone can learn!

Comment: This does not create a two-dimensional array. It creates a one-dimensional array of pointers to one-dimensional arrays. The resulting memory is generally not contiguous and cannot be passed to routines expecting two-dimensional arrays. It also causes unnecessary pointer lookups and prevents the compiler from making certain optimizations that are possible with two-dimensional arrays.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: even if its not contiguous it can be passed to functions right?

Comment: It will not serve as a two-dimensional array when passed to a function expecting a two-dimensional array. It could be passed to a function expecting a pointer to an array of pointers to arrays of objects. They are not the same thing, and needless pointers-to-pointers should be avoided.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: [Beginner] anyway won't it gets converted to pointer? (int **arr)?

Comment: No, an expression of type `int foo[m][n]` (array of array of int) is converted to `int (*)[n]` (pointer to array of int). Only the first dimension is converted. `int (*)[n]` and `int **` are **not** compatible.

Comment: @Dineshkumar Pointers are not arrays, arrays are not pointers, and they are not interchangeable.